# VBA enumerate through using enumchildwindows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create an excel document that communications with one of our external apps.

I have sendmessage working well in order to WM_GETTEXT from a specific window, however i can't get to the next childwindow as the class names are all the same:

[image]

My first code grabs the text from the very first class under the parentwindow named "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.2004eee"

```
 Grange = FindWindow(vbNullString, "General Account Enquiry")
 Account_number = FindWindowEx(Grange, 0&,   "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.2004eee", vbNullString)

 the_count = SendMessage(Account_number, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0&, 0&)

 Buffer$ = Space$(the_count)
 Call SendMessageByString(Account_number, WM_GETTEXT, the_count + 1, Buffer$)
```

But i need to also grab the text from the circled red box, which has the same class name. I only have experience with API calls where the class names are unique.

I've been told by a very helpful stackoverflow contributor to use enumchildwindows to cycle through the 5 other child windows of the same name, but after a few days searching i havn't been able to find the right code to do this.

Is anyone able to help or provide an example code that i can work with?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Looks like i managed to figure it out about 5 minutes after posting this,

Grange = FindWindow(vbNullString, "General Account Enquiry")

```
Account_number = FindWindowEx(Grange, 0&, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.2004eee", vbNullString)
Account_number2 = FindWindowEx(Grange, Account_number, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.2004eee", vbNullString)
Account_number3 = FindWindowEx(Grange, Account_number2, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.2004eee", vbNullString)
Account_number4 = FindWindowEx(Grange, Account_number3, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.2004eee", vbNullString)
Account_number5 = FindWindowEx(Grange, Account_number4, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.2004eee", vbNullString)
Account_number6 = FindWindowEx(Grange, Account_number5, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.2004eee", vbNullString)
Account_number7 = FindWindowEx(Grange, Account_number6, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.2004eee", vbNullString)

the_count = SendMessage(Account_number6, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0&, 0&)

Buffer$ = Space$(the_count)
Call SendMessageByString(Account_number6, WM_GETTEXT, the_count + 1, Buffer$)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = Buffer$
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the declarations of your API functions.